# Bitcoin peer info

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

Why when I run in the node bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo the list is an empty array? Do I need to let time to connect other peers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bitcoind should connect to other nodes within a few minutes. If it is connected to even one node bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo will return an array with connected nodes. If your array is empty, your node likely isn't connected to the internet.